# How to join and get data from two tables in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm working on a laravel project.
I'v got two tables : company, Prouct
Every company has many products . I want to display the company name and logo along with the product details .

```
class Company extends Model
{

// 
    public function products()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('System\Product','company_id');
    }
}

...........
    class Product extends Model
{
   public function company()
    {
      return $this->belongsTo('Systems\Company','id'); 
        }
}
```

..........

```
company_table
id   company_name  company_logo
 1       MDE        image.png
procut_table
id  product_name  price  company_id
1     7-up         200      1
```

How I want to dispaly it?

I want to display it like this :

```
Product_name
price
company_name
company_logo
```

How can I write a query in laravel to give me this result?
...............

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    class Company extends Model
    {

        public function products()
        {
            return $this->hasMany('System\Product','company_id','id');
        }
    }


    class Product extends Model
    {
       public function company()
        {
          return $this->belongsTo('Systems\Company','company_id','id'); 
            }
    }
```

In your **controller**, you can get like this.

```
$products = Product::with('company')->get();

    foreach ($products as $product) {
       echo $product->company->name; //MDE
       echo $product->company->company_logo; //image.png
       echo $product->price; //200

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `join`, You can use the following query

```
$result = DB::table('Product')->join('Company', 'Product.company_id', '=', 'Company.id')->get();
```

To get your result

Answer (score 0):

You can call for your products and load it's relation `company`.

```php
$products = Product::with('company')->get();
```

Then you can access the company of each product

```
@foreach($products as $product)
    {{$product->name}}<br/>
    {{$product->price}}<br/>
    {{$product->company->name}}<br/>
    {{$product->company->logo}}<br/>
@endforeach
```